# Changing URL in bbappend causes yocto error

Tags: build, yocto, openembedded, yocto-recipe, yocto-layer

I added a kernel bbappend file that was supposed to override the SRC_URI to point to my github developer repo instead of the public repo. But that change of 1 line alone caused yocto error:

```
ERROR: An uncaught exception occurred in runqueue############################                                                                 | ETA:  0:00:00Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/runqueue.py", line 1243, in RunQueueData.prepare_task_hash(tid='/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xboard_5.10.bb:do_fetch'):
         def prepare_task_hash(self, tid):
    >        bb.parse.siggen.prep_taskhash(tid, self.runtaskentries[tid].depends, self.dataCaches[mc_from_tid(tid)])
             self.runtaskentries[tid].hash = bb.parse.siggen.get_taskhash(tid, self.runtaskentries[tid].depends, self.dataCaches[mc_from_tid(tid)])
  File "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../poky/meta/lib/oe/sstatesig.py", line 146, in SignatureGeneratorOEEquivHash.prep_taskhash(tid='/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xboard_5.10.bb:do_fetch', deps=set(), dataCache=<bb.cache.CacheData object at 0x7f773b213880>):
         def prep_taskhash(self, tid, deps, dataCache):
    >        super().prep_taskhash(tid, deps, dataCache)
             if hasattr(self, "extramethod"):
  File "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/siggen.py", line 248, in SignatureGeneratorOEEquivHash.prep_taskhash(tid='/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xboard_5.10.bb:do_fetch', deps=set(), dataCache=<bb.cache.CacheData object at 0x7f773b213880>):
                 else:
    >                checksums = bb.fetch2.get_file_checksums(dataCache.file_checksums[fn][task], recipename, self.localdirsexclude)
                 for (f,cs) in checksums:
  File "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/fetch2/__init__.py", line 1215, in get_file_checksums(filelist='${@base_set_filespath(["/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xboard-5.10.158-cip22+git${SRCPV}", "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xboard", "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/files"], d)}/touch.cfg:False /mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/downloads/touch.cfg:False ${@base_set_filespath(["/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xboard-5.10.158-cip22+git${SRCPV}", "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xboard", "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/files"], d)}/0001-add-xzpi.dts.patch:False /mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/downloads/0001-add-xzpi.dts.patch:False ${@base_set_filespath(["/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xboard-5.10.158-cip22+git${SRCPV}", "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xboard", "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/files"], d)}/0001-workaround-boot-board.patch:False /mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/downloads/0001-workaround-boot-board.patch:False ${@base_set_filespath(["/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xboard-5.10.158-cip22+git${SRCPV}", "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xboard", "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/files"], d)}/sii.cfg:False /mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/downloads/sii.cfg:False ${@base_set_filespath(["/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xboard-5.10.158-cip22+git${SRCPV}", "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xboard", "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/files"], d)}/0001-Fixed-an-issue-that-caused-flicker-when-outputting-t.patch:False /mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/downloads/0001-Fixed-an-issue-that-caused-flicker-when-outputting-t.patch:False  /mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/poky/meta/files/common-licenses/MIT:True', pn='linux-xboard', localdirsexclude=['CVS', '.bzr', '.git', '.hg', '.osc', '.p4', '.repo', '.svn']):
         """
    >    return _checksum_cache.get_checksums(filelist, pn, localdirsexclude)

  File "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/checksum.py", line 103, in FileChecksumCache.get_checksums(filelist='${@base_set_filespath(["/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xboard-5.10.158-cip22+git${SRCPV}", "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xboard", "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/files"], d)}/touch.cfg:False /mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/downloads/touch.cfg:False ${@base_set_filespath(["/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xboard-5.10.158-cip22+git${SRCPV}", "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xboard", "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/files"], d)}/0001-add-xzpi.dts.patch:False /mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/downloads/0001-add-xzpi.dts.patch:False ${@base_set_filespath(["/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xboard-5.10.158-cip22+git${SRCPV}", "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xboard", "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/files"], d)}/0001-workaround-boot-board.patch:False /mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/downloads/0001-workaround-boot-board.patch:False ${@base_set_filespath(["/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xboard-5.10.158-cip22+git${SRCPV}", "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xboard", "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/files"], d)}/sii.cfg:False /mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/downloads/sii.cfg:False ${@base_set_filespath(["/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xboard-5.10.158-cip22+git${SRCPV}", "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xboard", "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/files"], d)}/0001-Fixed-an-issue-that-caused-flicker-when-outputting-t.patch:False /mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/downloads/0001-Fixed-an-issue-that-caused-flicker-when-outputting-t.patch:False  /mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/poky/meta/files/common-licenses/MIT:True', pn='linux-xboard', localdirsexclude=['CVS', '.bzr', '.git', '.hg', '.osc', '.p4', '.repo', '.svn']):
             for pth in filelist.split():
    >            exist = pth.split(":")[1]
                 if exist == "False":
IndexError: list index out of range

ERROR: Running idle function
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/runqueue.py", line 1243, in RunQueueData.prepare_task_hash(tid='/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xboard_5.10.bb:do_fetch'):
         def prepare_task_hash(self, tid):
    >        bb.parse.siggen.prep_taskhash(tid, self.runtaskentries[tid].depends, self.dataCaches[mc_from_tid(tid)])
             self.runtaskentries[tid].hash = bb.parse.siggen.get_taskhash(tid, self.runtaskentries[tid].depends, self.dataCaches[mc_from_tid(tid)])
  File "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../poky/meta/lib/oe/sstatesig.py", line 146, in SignatureGeneratorOEEquivHash.prep_taskhash(tid='/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xboard_5.10.bb:do_fetch', deps=set(), dataCache=<bb.cache.CacheData object at 0x7f773b213880>):
         def prep_taskhash(self, tid, deps, dataCache):
    >        super().prep_taskhash(tid, deps, dataCache)
             if hasattr(self, "extramethod"):
  File "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/siggen.py", line 248, in SignatureGeneratorOEEquivHash.prep_taskhash(tid='/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xboard_5.10.bb:do_fetch', deps=set(), dataCache=<bb.cache.CacheData object at 0x7f773b213880>):
                 else:
    >                checksums = bb.fetch2.get_file_checksums(dataCache.file_checksums[fn][task], recipename, self.localdirsexclude)
                 for (f,cs) in checksums:
  File "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/fetch2/__init__.py", line 1215, in get_file_checksums(filelist='${@base_set_filespath(["/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xboard-5.10.158-cip22+git${SRCPV}", "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xboard", "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/files"], d)}/touch.cfg:False /mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/downloads/touch.cfg:False ${@base_set_filespath(["/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xboard-5.10.158-cip22+git${SRCPV}", "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xboard", "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/files"], d)}/0001-add-xzpi.dts.patch:False /mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/downloads/0001-add-xzpi.dts.patch:False ${@base_set_filespath(["/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xboard-5.10.158-cip22+git${SRCPV}", "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xboard", "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/files"], d)}/0001-workaround-boot-board.patch:False /mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/downloads/0001-workaround-boot-board.patch:False ${@base_set_filespath(["/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xboard-5.10.158-cip22+git${SRCPV}", "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xboard", "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/files"], d)}/sii.cfg:False /mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/downloads/sii.cfg:False ${@base_set_filespath(["/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xboard-5.10.158-cip22+git${SRCPV}", "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xboard", "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/files"], d)}/0001-Fixed-an-issue-that-caused-flicker-when-outputting-t.patch:False /mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/downloads/0001-Fixed-an-issue-that-caused-flicker-when-outputting-t.patch:False  /mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/poky/meta/files/common-licenses/MIT:True', pn='linux-xboard', localdirsexclude=['CVS', '.bzr', '.git', '.hg', '.osc', '.p4', '.repo', '.svn']):
         """
    >    return _checksum_cache.get_checksums(filelist, pn, localdirsexclude)

  File "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/checksum.py", line 103, in FileChecksumCache.get_checksums(filelist='${@base_set_filespath(["/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xboard-5.10.158-cip22+git${SRCPV}", "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xboard", "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/files"], d)}/touch.cfg:False /mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/downloads/touch.cfg:False ${@base_set_filespath(["/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xboard-5.10.158-cip22+git${SRCPV}", "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xboard", "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/files"], d)}/0001-add-xzpi.dts.patch:False /mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/downloads/0001-add-xzpi.dts.patch:False ${@base_set_filespath(["/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xboard-5.10.158-cip22+git${SRCPV}", "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xboard", "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/files"], d)}/0001-workaround-boot-board.patch:False /mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/downloads/0001-workaround-boot-board.patch:False ${@base_set_filespath(["/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xboard-5.10.158-cip22+git${SRCPV}", "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xboard", "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/files"], d)}/sii.cfg:False /mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/downloads/sii.cfg:False ${@base_set_filespath(["/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xboard-5.10.158-cip22+git${SRCPV}", "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xboard", "/mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/../meta-xboard/meta-common/recipes-kernel/linux/files"], d)}/0001-Fixed-an-issue-that-caused-flicker-when-outputting-t.patch:False /mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/build/downloads/0001-Fixed-an-issue-that-caused-flicker-when-outputting-t.patch:False  /mnt/host_fs/Workspace/preetam/NewBoard/new_release/yocto/poky/meta/files/common-licenses/MIT:True', pn='linux-xboard', localdirsexclude=['CVS', '.bzr', '.git', '.hg', '.osc', '.p4', '.repo', '.svn']):
             for pth in filelist.split():
    >            exist = pth.split(":")[1]
                 if exist == "False":
IndexError: list index out of range


Summary: There were 6 WARNING messages shown.
Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: How does your bbappend look like? At the first sight this looks like a syntax error somewhere in there.

Comment: surprisingly this was caused because my ssh keys changed. For some odd reason the key  loaded in ssh-agent is different from the one in .ssh. A secondary reason is the url itself.
I used the same url as github clone i.e git@github.com:<username>. I had to change that to git://git@github.com/<username>/...;protocol=ssh

Comment: That `:` in the url was the syntax error.

Comment: But that's how gihub page shows and it work in git clone command. I didn't know yocto needed a different format.

Comment: can you update your question, show us your modification !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url needs to change:

Original from github: `git@github.com:<username>/repo`

Modified for bitbake `git://git@github.com/<username>/repo`

Also `protocol=git` needs to change to `protocol=ssh`.

In addition, the ssh agent was showing a different key than the ssh file. So remove the keys, and added a new one on system and updated it in github.